# Method call to another file

Tags: java, methods

I have two files:

- Test.java
- Other.java

I wanted to learn how to call the file "Test.java" a method that is in another file "other.java"

Thank you!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You either create an object of type `Other` and then call the method on that object:

```
//in the Test class

    Other obj = new Other();
    obj.methodFromOther();
```

or if the method is static just call:

```
//in the Test class

    Other.methodFromOther();
```

Maybe you should follow [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) to learn about the java programming language.